# Update div after form submit

Tags: php, mysql, database, refresh

my first post on Stackoverflow.

I'm building a page with bootstrap and php. 
I have a value load from a database in a text field in a div.

In the same page I have a button loading a modal where I have a form with the same value load in a text field.

So if the user changes the value in the form and hits update I would like the modal to close and the value update on the page.

All the modal, form, load and save database is working. The place where I'm stuck is the div refresh data part.

Any advice.

Comment: You need to show us some code what did you do until now. Nobody here can't make all code for you.

Comment: Sorry about that I will as soon I came back home. I'm in the train right now. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can change the content of the div by using `text`

```
$("div#some_id").text("new text")
```

Or add HTML using `html`

```
$("div#some_id").html("<h1>Hello</h1>")
```

Or use a variable

```
var post_name = "Update div after form submit";
$("div#some_id").text("Thanks for adding a new post called '" + post_name + "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery ajax to post you can do this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php file name',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: 'somedata',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#divID').html(data)
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Failed to load");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IF is a Input : 
api.jquery.com/val/

```
$(element_to_change).val(ajaxResponse.new_value)
```

OR
   api.jquery.com/html/

```
$(element_to_change).html(ajaxResponse.new_value)
```

## Modal

*If modal is JqueryUI Dialog*

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close

```
$(element_modal).dialog( "close" );
```

*So You can do*

```
$.ajax({
    success : function ( ajaxResponse ) {
      $(element_modal).dialog({
             close: function( event, ui ) {
             $(element_to_change).html(ajaxResponse.new_value) 
             //OR
              $(element_to_change).val(ajaxResponse.new_value)
          }
      });
    }
});
```

*If is not a jqueryUI Dialog*

```
$(element_modal).hide();
```

Or Remove element from DOM

```
$(element_modal).remove();
```